# How do I add a title to my MatPlotLib basemap?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried

```
matplotlib.pyplot.title("Analysis of Tsunamis in Southeast Asia")
```

but the Python interpreter notes that `NameError: name 'matplotlib' is not defined` even though I am sure that I imported pyplot earlier:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
```

How can I add a title to my map?

Comment: Can you show the lines of code that are creating the map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that you imported pyplot like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# or from matplotlib import pyplot
```

In which case you'd need to do

```
plt.title("Analysis of Tsunamis in Southeast Asia")
# or pyplot.title("Analysis of Tsunamis in Southeast Asia")
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried using `as`, and the error goes away, but there's still no title on my map.

Comment: As Thomas K mentions, you'll need to post some of your code so we can help.

Comment: Oh thanks, I figured it out. My map was for some reason covering up my title. However, the `as` fixed my original error, so thanks!

Comment: Good on you for fixing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you might have over thought yourself.  By importing the routine matplotlib.pyplot, you have brought the subroutines of pyplot into your current work space.  Therefore, using the entire name of the function is like saying

```
matplotlib.pyplot.matplotlib.pyplot.title
```

-- which is why it's not defined.  Have you tried just calling:

```
title("Analysis of Tsunamis in Southeast Asia")
```

After looking at some of my subroutines, I think that might be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

try using

from matplotlib.pyplot import *
title("Analysis of Tsunamis in Southeast Asia")